# How to relate a pivot field in a belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Actually I have this situation:

- 1 user belongs to many customers
- In this relationship - `customers_users` - I need to save `created_user_id` ie, **who create this relationship**.

---

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project\DB\Customer', 'customers_users')
        ->withPivot('created_user_id');
}
```

---

How can I relate this extra field in my Eloquent model? I need to access that information like this:

```
@foreach ($user->customers => $customer)
    {!! $customer->pivot->createdUser->name !!}
@endforeach
```

The only way I make it work, was making a **manually join**, but I want to do that using the eloquent.

If you need more information, tell me.

Answer (score -1):

If the customer has not been saved yet

```
$user->customers()->save($customer, ['created_user_id' => $creatorUser->id]);
```

If the custemer has already been saved

```
$user->customers()->attach($customer->id, ['created_user_id' => $creatorUser->id]);
```

Comment: In my customers table I do not have `created_user_id`, this field is in `customers_users` table only. I need that to know **who created this relationship - customer x user**, understand?

Comment: That code will update the `customers_users` table, not the `customers` one. The second parameter of both `save()` and `attach()` is for dealing with pivots

Comment: I'ill test that, but my problem it's about how to configure the relationship not how to save, understand?